# loop density curve in R

Tags: r, for-loop

```
nummonty<- c(09,10,11,12)
monty <- c('Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec')
daa <- c(rlnorm(1000), rlnorm(1000), rlnorm(1000),rlnorm(1000))
dat <- data.frame(nummonty,monty,daa)

dfun <- function(x, a, b) 1/(sqrt(2*pi*b(x-1)))*exp(-0.5*((log(x-a)/b)^2))

#Fit the density curves for each "month"
#dens <- density(dat$daa, n = nrow(daa))
#df_dens <- data.frame(x = dens$x, y = dens$y)

#Fit the data for all months 
fit <- nls(y ~ dfun(x, a, b), data = df_dens, start = list(a = mean(dat$daa[i]), b = sd(dat$daa[i])))
```

How do I include for each `montyg` type the density curve and extract the fitted data including the `nls`coeff `a`and `b` in a separate `csv` file? For a single case, the solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64116691/r-function-to-find-suitable-values-for-fitting-constants) but I'd like to loop it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide reproducible code for a single case, specific to your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is possible using `patchwork` and avoiding the use of loop with a function. You can split your data in a list by month and the fit the models. Then, you can arrange the plots as desired. Just few thoughts in your code. You literally took the function from the other post and changed from normal to lognormal. Be careful about that because setting logs in `dfun()` without knowing what will happen is not a good practice. In most of cases, `NA` will be produced and you will get errors in `stat_function()`. For that reason and to show you how to do, I will use the same function as in the cited post. After that you can adjust to your real data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)
#Data
nummonty<- c(09,10,11,12)
monty <- c('Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec')
daa <- c(rnorm(1000), rnorm(1000), rnorm(1000),rnorm(1000))
dat <- data.frame(nummonty,monty,daa)
gdat <- data.frame(montyg=unique(dat$monty),nummontyg=unique(dat$nummonty))
#Function
dfun <- function(x, a, b) 1/(sqrt(2*pi)*b)*exp(-0.5*((x-a)^2/(2*b^2))) 
#Create a data list
List <- split(dat,dat$monty)
#Function
myfun <- function(x)
{
  #Fit the density curves for each "month"
  dens <- density(x$daa, n = nrow(x))
  df_dens <- data.frame(x = dens$x, y = dens$y)
  #Fit the model
  fit <- nls(y ~ dfun(x, a, b),data = df_dens,start = list(a = mean(x$daa), b = sd(x$daa)))
  #Plot
  G1 <- ggplot(x, aes(x = daa)) + 
    geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), binwidth = 0.5)+
    stat_function(fun = dfun,
                  args = list(a = coef(fit)[1], b = coef(fit)[2]))+
    ggtitle(unique(x$monty))
  return(G1)
}
#Apply
List2 <- lapply(List,myfun)
#Wrap plots
G <- wrap_plots(List2,ncol = 2)
```

Output:

[image]

**Update:** To extract coefs try this:

```
#Function
myfun2 <- function(x)
{
  #Fit the density curves for each "month"
  dens <- density(x$daa, n = nrow(x))
  df_dens <- data.frame(x = dens$x, y = dens$y)
  #Fit the model
  fit <- nls(y ~ dfun(x, a, b),data = df_dens,start = list(a = mean(x$daa), b = sd(x$daa)))
  #Plot
  C1 <- coef(fit)
  return(C1)
}
#Apply
List2 <- lapply(List,myfun2)
```

Output:

```
List2
$Dec
        a         b 
0.0426051 0.9513849 

$Nov
         a          b 
0.02477635 0.96920246 

$Oct
         a          b 
0.08146357 0.98437906 

$Sep
          a           b 
-0.02620755  0.93557576
```

Comment: thanks Duck :). Any tips on how to extract the ```nls``` coeff. values for each month?

Comment: @P.Chakytei Yes, you can modify the function and create a new list to store the coefs. Let me add that code in few seconds!

Comment: @P.Chakytei I have added an update. I hope that can help you!